# Transformation of an improper integral of the square root of a rational function

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Why is this true?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt=4\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt$$

I know that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt$$
but after?

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt\tag1$$

Now we have
$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt$$$$=2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt+2\int_{1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt\tag2$$

Then, by setting $\frac 1t=u$, the second integral of $(2)$ will be
$$2\int_{1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt$$$$=2\int_{1}^{0}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(u^{-2}-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)(u^{-1})^{2n}}{(u^{-1})^{2n+2}-1}}\cdot\frac{du}{-u^2}$$$$=2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}-\frac{(n+1)u^{2n}}{(1-u^{2n+2})^2}}du$$
$$=2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{(t^2-1)^2}-\frac{(n+1)t^{2n}}{(t^{2n+2}-1)^2}}dt.$$